# excel 2013 Add-in development in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create `excel 2013 Add-in` in `visual studio 2012`. But it is not showing `excel 2013 Add-in template`, although `excel 2010 Add-in template` is there. Here is my `VS 2012` screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `OfficeToolsForVS2012RTW`. You can download in from [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx/getinstaller/OfficeToolsForVS2012RTW.appids)